# Forward port error when debug kubernet pods in VS Code

Tags: python, kubernetes, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-remote

I am trying to use VS Code to debug kubernetes pod in python. I have successfully debug one pod with **Kuberentes: Debug (Attach)** command. However, when I tried to debug another pod with the same command, I got error:

> [E1105 11:54:06.281402 25535 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 10000 -> 5678: error forwarding port 5678 tp pod

The same port forwarding works fine for the first pod. Only when I try to attach another port, I got the error. Before I tried to attach the second pod, I have disattached the first pod already.

I suspect that the port is still being used by the first pod so the second pod could not be forwarded.
*Does anyone know how to change the port number in vscode and how to fix this problem?*
Thanks

Comment: Port is configured in launchSettings.json file, property named debugPort, you could try changing that

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have searched in my computer and could not find launchSettings.json. Do you know where is it or how to create it?

Comment: What extension you using to attach VScode to kuber?

Comment: I use Kubernetes extension from Microsoft. version is v1.2.1

Comment: Oh, ok, thought of different one. you could check here - https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/blob/master/debug-on-kubernetes.md  there is an Extension setting named vs-kubernetes.nodejs-debug-port where you could specify a port, only thing that is not really clear, is that should or should not you replace there "nodejs" by "python" for your case

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. After many try and error, I figured it out the reason. To debug the kubernetes pod in python, we have to put ptvsd.enable_attach() and other ptvsd command in the main thread.

Comment: I solved the issue after try and error. To fix this issue, we have to put the ptvsd command in main thread.

Comment: @FrankWang if you're looking for a way to do this without modifying your pods' code, I wrote an open source project that does this: https://docs.robusta.dev/master/catalog/actions/python-troubleshooting.html#python-debugger